# How to ignore missing files when loading many CSV files in a dataframe in Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I'm writing PySpark script in Azure Synapse Notebook. It's supposed to load a long list of CSV files into a dataframe like this:

```
%%pyspark

path = [
'abfss://mycontainer@mylake.dfs.core.windows.net/sku-934/data.csv', 
'abfss://mycontainer@mylake.dfs.core.windows.net/sku-594/data.csv',
'abfss://mycontainer@mylake.dfs.core.windows.net/sku-365/data.csv',
# Many more paths here
]
 
df = spark.read.options(header=True).csv(path)
```

However, I cannot guarantee that files at all of those paths exist. Sometimes they don't. If that's the case, the whole script stops with `AnalysisException: Path does not exist`

**Question** - can I instruct spark in Azure Synapse Notebook to ignore missing files and load only those that are there?

What I already tried to solve this - googling suggested I could do `spark.sql("set spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true")`, but for some reason it had no effect. Maybe that doesn't work in Synapse, or it's intended for a different use case. My knowledge about this is very limited, so I can't tell.

Comment: Are you selectively reading specific files or are you okay with reading all files under `.csv('...windows.net')`?   or with regex like `.csv('...windows.net/*/data.csv')`?

Comment: @Emma I'm selectively reading specific files. Unfortunately, I cannot select exactly those files that I need with a wildcard or regex

Comment: Add a function to check for the existence and create a list of existing ones before reading them.

Comment: @Bala's comment is more solid solution.  but fyi `ignoreCorruptFiles` is for if contents is not a valid csv.  and I think `spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles` is closer to what you are looking for, though this only works for missing files and won't work for missing directories.

Comment: Use a Get Metadata or Lookup activity to get the files that actually exist, and pass that into the notebook from a Synapse Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is not possible.

Either insert those missing file with script with no data ahead of running app or build the valid list first.

Well known issue.